# Refresh token for Google APIs to keep user logged in

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, actions-on-google

I am developing an App on Actions on Google that uses Google Calendar. At the start of a user's first interaction, they are prompted to link their Google account for access to the calendar. But then for nearly every future interaction, the user has to authenticate again.

My code to get the access token from the user data is below. I'm not sure if there's a way to get the refresh token to add to the credentials. I've seen you should include `"access_type": "offline"` in the request in other answers, but I'm not sure where I'd put it in my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
const googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

function getAuth(app) {
    var accessToken = app.getUser().accessToken;
    var clientId = CLIENT_ID;
    var clientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET;
    var redirectUrl = 'https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/my_app_name';
    var auth = new googleAuth();
    var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);
    var token = {
        "access_token": accessToken,
        "refresh_token": "",
        "access_type": "offline", //Not sure if these attributes should be here
        "approval_prompt": "force",
        "immediate": true,
        "token_type": "Bearer"
    };
    oauth2Client.credentials = token;
    return oauth2Client;
}

calendar.freebusy.query ({
    auth: getAuth(app), //need a Google OAuth client here for API request
    headers: { "content-type" : "application/json" },
    resource:{
        items: [
            {
                id: "primary"
            }
        ],
        timeMin: startDate.format(),
        timeMax: endDate.format(),
        timeZone: timeZoneId
    }, function(err, response) {
        console.log('Success!');
    }
});
```

Not sure if this helps, but on the very first interaction a user has to select an account and agree to the calendar permission, but on subsequent interactions they just have to tap "link account to Google" and it automatically authenticates them.

EDIT:

This is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8lQB.png) of the prompt I get on every new interaction with the app. It was my understanding that account linking is only done on the very first interaction with the app, then the accounts are linked for good and the user need not be prompted again. I am not receiving any errors, I was just wondering if and how I can modify my current code to not prompt the user to link their account on every single interaction.

Comment: It isn't clear from your description what problem you're encountering. Can you please update your question to say what you're seeing, what errors you're getting, etc?

Comment: I updated the post to be more specific.

Comment: That sounds more like a problem with how you're requesting account linking in the first place. Can you describe how you're configuring and requesting account linking?

Comment: I'm using Authorization Code as the grant type on the Actions on Google console (rather than implicit). I got the client ID and secret from the Google API console. My authorization URL is: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth`, my token URL is: `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token`, and my scope  is: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar`.

Comment: To further clarify, I added how I'm using the oAuth2Client in the API request in the code. I make 1-3 such requests to the calendar API in each invocation of the app. I don't have any code to actually request the account linking, Actions on Google is handling all of that using the above information as far as I know.

Comment: Are you using gactions or api.ai?

Comment: I'm using api.ai. I have checked the "sign in required for welcome intent" box on integrations. None of my intents involve account linking because I thought it's all handled by the assistant.